# Error when using anonymous user and pserver

Tags: ant, cvs, vcs-checkout

I have setup an anonymous cvs user to be able to check out my project from cvs without having to enter a password.

However, when I try to login to cvs using the following command

**cvs -d: pserver: anonymous@[HOSTNAME]:/home/cvs/cvsroot login**

And then presss enter when prompted for a password

**CVS Password:**

I get the following error message

**Internal error: get_cvs_port_number called for invalid connection method (ext): Invalid argument**

This happens when trying to run this command on the same server that cvs is installed on. However, if I use this command on another server, it logs in without an error.

I would like to run this command from the same server that CVS is installed, and then put it into an ant script to be able to do a CVS checkout without a prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the following code

Add line below to a shell script, and call shell script from ant build file using the exec task

cvs -d ":pserver:[USERNAME]:[PASSWORD]@[SERVER]:/home/cvs/cvsroot" checkout -r $1 [MODULE_NAME]